# Hover over figure and change fig caption?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm following this tutorial: http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/06/18/caption-hover-effects/. Going in it step by step so I know what i'm doing. I was surprised to learn this effect is done all in css.

Anyway I got stuck at this part in cs-style3

```
.no-touch .cs-style-3 figure:hover figcaption,
.cs-style-3 figure.cs-hover figcaption {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0px);
    transition: transform 0.4s, opacity 0.1s;
}
```

What is .cs-hover? I search for this is this some kind of special css3 thing? Because it isnt' a class in the file. And I can't get this to work.

I'm trying to hover over the figure/img and the figcaption is suppose to slide up.

I was thinking of trying figure:hover figcaption{} but this doesn't work either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you go through the code you'll see that they include `<script src="js/toucheffects.js"></script>`. This script says:

> // for touch devices: add class cs-hover to the figures when touching
>   the items

Answer (score 0):

On the demo page there are a lot of examples. The author used the .cs-style-"number" class to differentiate bewteen the different styles.

[image]

This means you should add the class to your code as well, just like in the inspector in the image above. I hope this helps you, otherwise leave a comment and we'll see if we can help you further

Comment: I was able to figure it out my own way, i did the animation transition using query. I don't know why my css styles couldn't do the transition like the demo. I will have to do more investigating on this issue.

Comment: I suggest you try again and do it using css3. I'd use jquery animations only as a fallback for old browser (you can detect those who don't support transitions with modernizr.js), because css3 animation are much more performant and nicer to see

Comment: i'm still alot confused on how hover states over divs work, is it just like a tags, a:hover? Like is it possible to div:hover and cause a reaction to an image?  I did google search css3 transition and I copy and paste them and they dont work for me, i'm using an up to date safari browser.

Comment: I made this, hope it helps:
http://jsfiddle.net/BuPxh/

It shows a couple of use cases for hovers. Basically you can add :hover to any selector. If it ends there (for example div:hover {}), the styles declared in that selector will apply to the element itself, but you're also free to style child elements of the hovered element (example div:hover img {border: 1px solid black}). This will add a black border to the image that is inside the hovered div.